# What is the default z-index of relative positioned element?

Tags: css

Good afternoon,

I've made a very simple page demonstrating the different position types we can use in `css` for a new starter at our company, and quite embarrassingly this has exposed a gap in my own knowledge.

I have positioned all elements on the page but I've noticed that my relative positioned element will sit on top of my sticky element when the page is scrolled. It is almost like it has a `z-index` which is higher than my sticky element - I haven't set any `z-index` values though.

Is this the correct behavior given code I have provided? Apologies if this is really simple stuff, It has me sitting here scratching my head.

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/sconner87/pen/GyeEOq)

```css
body {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    height: 3000px;
}

.relative {
    width: 20%;
    min-height: 200px;
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
.sticky {
    position: sticky;
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 20%;
    height: 200px;
    top:0;

}
.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: aqua;
    color: black;
    height: 200px;
    width: 20%;
    right: 200px;
    top: 300px;
}
.absolute {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 10px;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 20%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}
.static {
    position: static;
    width: 20%;
    background-color: blueviolet;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<body> 

<div class="sticky">
    This is a sticky div
</div>

<div class="relative">
    This is a relative div
</div>

<div class="absolute">
    This is an absolute div
</div>

<div class="static">
    This is a normal div
</div>

<div class="fixed">
    This is a fixed div
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: You can fix it by using z-index: -1; on the sticky container.
Not really sure why it behaves like that though

Comment: Yeah, I know how I'd go about fixing it - it was more curiosity as to why it behaves this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is normal behavior. Your relatively positioned element appears after your stickily positioned element in the source, so its natural stack level is higher and therefore it appears above the stickily positioned element. See [section 9.9 of CSS2](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visuren.html#layers), or [section 11 of css-position](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-position/#layered-presentation).

Stickily positioned elements obey the same stacking rules as relatively and absolutely positioned elements.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that makes sense!

Answer (score 3):

If two elements are in the same stacking context (have the same `z-index` value), then the browser will just look at the order that they are inserted in the dom: the last one would appear on top of the previous.
Here's more info on this topic: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/Stacking_without_z-index

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

> When the z-index and position properties aren’t involved, the rules
>   are pretty simple: basically, the stacking order is the same as the
>   order of appearance in the HTML. (OK, it’s actually a little more
>   complicated than that, but as long as you’re not using negative
>   margins to overlap inline elements, you probably won’t encounter the
>   edge cases.)

---

> When you introduce the position property into the mix, any positioned
>   elements (and their children) are displayed in front of any
>   non-positioned elements. (To say an element is “positioned” means that
>   it has a position value other than static, e.g., relative, absolute,
>   etc.)

https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

Z-index only works on elements that have been position with `absolute`, `relative`, `fixed`. As your sticky element appears before your static element in the HTML, it will take precedence in the stacking order.